# How to Remove $id from list in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

```
Here is my List

{ $id: "1"
cashOnDeliveryCharges: ""
deliveryMethod: ""
order_date: "06-12-2019"
order_no: "ORD000105"
paymentMethod: "Shopping Wallet"
registered_email: "Sambasivarao@smartsoft.in"
shippingAddress: "DELDD, 2981, 161, 13-8269"
shippingCharges: ""
store: ""
total: "AED 3600.00"
items: {$id: "2", name: "Batch Soap", qty: 8, amount: 450, productId: 15}
}
```

Here I don't want "$id" from this List Please any one help me

Comment: have you tried 'delete'? like person = {name :'asdsa', age:20} then you can use delete person.age to delete his age

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete);

Try this:

```js
let item = {
  $id: "1",
  cashOnDeliveryCharges: "",
  deliveryMethod: "",
  order_date: "06-12-2019",
  order_no: "ORD000105",
  paymentMethod: "Shopping Wallet",
  registered_email: "Sambasivarao@smartsoft.in",
  shippingAddress: "DELDD, 2981, 161, 13-8269",
  shippingCharges: "",
  store: "",
  total: "AED 3600.00",
  items: { $id: "2", name: "Batch Soap", qty: 8, amount: 450, productId: 15 }
} 
delete item['$id'];
delete item.items['$id'];
console.log(item);
```